# Do without USES_CONVERSION macro

Tags: c++, macros, atl

I have this code that uses the `USE_CONVERSION` macro in a C++ project...

I was wondering if this is written well, (not written by me), and if there's any better ways to do it, without the `USES_CONVERSION` and W2A macros.

```
STDMETHODIMP CInterpreter::GetStringVar(BSTR bstrNamespace, BSTR bstrVar, BSTR *pbstrValue)
{
USES_CONVERSION;

try
{
    if (!pbstrValue) return E_POINTER;

    char* pszNamespace= W2A(_bstr_t(bstrNamespace).operator wchar_t*());
    char* pszVar= W2A(_bstr_t(bstrVar).operator wchar_t*());  // Is this not better done another way????
    
    char pszErrStr[kPYTHONERRBUFSIZE];
    char pszStrValue[kPYTHONSTRVALUESIZE];
    BOOL bResult= Python_GetStringVar(pszNamespace, pszVar, pszErrStr, pszStrValue, kPYTHONSTRVALUESIZE);

    *pbstrValue= _bstr_t(pszStrValue).operator BSTR();

    if (!bResult)
        throw x::internal_error(A2W(pszErrStr));

    return S_OK;
}
}
```

Comment: Since there's also a BSTR, it looks like Microsoft's MFC/ATL stuff. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: BSTR is a Win32 (Platform SDK) type. _bstr_t is also part of the Platform SDK (it is used by #import).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the class-based `ATL::CA2W` and friends (in `atlconv.h`, I believe) that don't put the string on the stack and don't use macros. You don't need a `USES_CONVERSION` in the function:

`throw x::internal_error(ATL::CA2W(pszErrStr));`

Also, since your arguments are `BSTR (wchar_t *)`, you don't need to convert them to `_bstr_t`.

NOTE: The lifetime of the converted string is the lifetime of the `CW2A` object, so you will need to put it into a string class, e.g.:

`CStringA arg = CW2A(bstrArg);`

NOTE 2: `pbstrValue` is an output value. The `_bstr_t` instance will destroy the memory allocated for the `BSTR`. Therefore, you need to either use `SysAllocString` directly, or detach the `BSTR`:

`pbstrValue = SysAllocString(CA2W(retval));`

or:

`pbstrValue = CComBSTR(CA2W(retval)).Detach();`

NOTE 3: Explicit use of the conversion operators (`.operator BSTR()`) is not needed -- the compiler will call the correct one for you.

NOTE 4: Since this looks like a COM call, you really do not want to be throwing a C++ exception. You probably want to set an `IErrorInfo` object (probably with a helper):

`if (!bResult) { SetError(CA2W(errorStr)); return E_FAIL; }`